# Reusing activities in Android for a cyclical application

Tags: android, user-interface, android-activity, android-lifecycle, memory-efficient

In an Android Application I am working on, it is to be used in a very cyclical/circular way. Basically, there is a main screen which shows a status grid of a number of tracked entities.

The user can initiate a process by button press, which takes them to a new activity, where they can manipulate the grid items.

Once finished, it goes back to the main screen, who's grid is updated to reflect the new changes. On the right of the main screen, there is a list of upcoming tasks which are used to manipulate the grid, and they get checked as they are completed.

Now, as it stands, as you go around and around checking off these tasks, altering the grid contents, it is just making more and more activities and adding them to the stack.

What is the correct way to simply reuse these activities, or at least remove the old ones from the stack so they can be released from memory and the 'previous' button cant go back to them?

Im literally just starting intents - I have seen these flags but just had a stab with them and got nowhere.

```
Intent mainScreenIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(mainScreenIntent);
```

I do have a singleton which has my grid data models in it, so they are always accessible and only created once. The GridViewAdapter is stored in an object in there, so that is also not being re-created. Just the activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent(MyOldActivity.this, MyNewActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
startActivity(i);
```

Use this, so that the **OldActivity** is *deleted* from the ***stack history***.

Comment: So lets say the user goes through 3 different screens/activitys before they finish the procedure. I would want the stack history intact until they have hit the final 'finish' button which goes back to the main activity.

Would I need to keep a reference to each of those activitys in the middle and then call finish on them all? Or is there a bigger architecture problem here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want get rid of old `Activity`, just call the `finish()` method on old `Activity` after starting a new `Activity`.

```
Intent mainScreenIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(mainScreenIntent);
finish();
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!